# animate.css only works if "infinite" is added

Tags: html, css, animation, animate.css

My issue is that animations aren't displaying on my webpage, unless "infinite" is added to the class. Example:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
</head>
```

Scenario 1 (animated + rotateIn does nothing on the webpage):

```
<body>
 <img class="animated rotateIn" src="images/mackfilms.png" alt="">
</body>
```

Scenario 2 (adding infinite to the class makes the animation appear. But infinitely... ):

```
<body>
 <img class="animated rotateIn infinite" src="images/mackfilms.png" alt="">
</body>
```

This seems to be the case on any element that I use this combination with. Animations do NOT appear unless "infinite" is added, which is not the result I am aiming for.

Comment: Well. Now share your CSS. I can't see it in my magic crystal ball.

Comment: put your fiddle demo

Comment: what is infinite here?

Comment: fiddle = https://jsfiddle.net/z5qjzeht/
The fiddle shows the effect I'm trying to get. It of course works in the fiddle, but not on my project. Grr!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hide the object first. e.g. Add class of hidden. Then check if the object is in the viewport to remove the hidden class.

**Why?** Because css linear animations can't run on an object already displayed block and visible in the dom / viewport.

How does it work?
The object in this case the image will be:

```
opacity : 0
```

On the object entering the viewport the javascript will remove the hidden class and the animation will start.

To read up more on this please see here:

https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

All will be explained.

Comment: This did not seem to work for me and I unfortunately found no answers in the link you provided.  Thanks anyways Andy!

Comment: Are you using javascript on the page to remove classes?

Comment: Are you using javascript to remove classes?You can do a whole bunch of other stuff with animate.css when you combine it with jQuery or add your own CSS rules. Dynamically add animations using jQuery with ease:

$('#yourElement').addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');

Comment: Yes, the only way I have found to make an animation work so far is to have the classes added after the content loads.
Example:
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 200) {
    $('#ab').addClass('animated rotateIn');
  }
});

Comment: You haven't read my answer and understood it. Animations cannot work without first being hidden on the page. You need to read up more on css3 animations to understand.

Comment: After creating a JS function to removeClass('hidden') then addClass('animation') it seems to have worked. I appreciate the help Andy! Thank you!